# How to prove $A=\mathcal{O}_n$, use trace of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=B+C$, and $B=B^T$, $C=-C^T$, $BC=\mathcal{O}_n$. Prove that if $A^2=\mathcal{O}_n$, then $A=\mathcal{O}_n$.
I want to prove $B=C=
\mathcal{O}_n$, and I got that
$$A^2=B^2+CB+BC+C^2\implies0=\mathrm{tr}(A^2)=\mathrm{tr}(B^2)+\mathrm{tr}(C^2)$$
So$$\mathrm{tr}(BB^T)=\mathrm{tr}(CC^T)\geqslant0.$$
But I don't know how to go on.

Comment: What if $$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad C=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Then, if $A := B+C$, we have $BC = O$ and $A^2 = O$ but $A \ne O$.

Comment: @VIVID well$B=B'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it
$$BC=-B'C'=-(CB)'=O\implies CB=O\implies A^2=B^2+C^2=O.$$
$$B^2(B^2+C^2)=B^4+B^2C^2=O\implies B^4=O.$$
$$B^2(B^2)'=O\implies \mathrm{tr}(B^2(B^2)')=0\implies B^2=O\implies\mathrm{tr}(BB')=0\implies B=O.$$
$$C^2=O\implies\mathrm{tr}(CC')=O\implies C=O\implies A=B+C=O.$$

Answer (score 1):

I was reading your answer and it’s seems fine to me, but there is something that I want to say, just to make it clear. I’m gonna present here two possible resolutions.

I’ll start by a Lemma that will be important.

---

**Lemma.** Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{K})$ such that $A$ is symmetric matrix. Then, $A = \mathcal{O}_n$ if and only if $A^2$.

*Proof*. $\implies.$ This is trivial. If $A= \mathcal{O}_n$, then clearly $A^2=\mathcal{O}_n$.

$\Longleftarrow.$ Suppose that $A^2 = \mathcal{O}_n$. Since, $A$ is symmetric, we have that $AA^T = \mathcal{O}_n = A^TA$. Let $i \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $i \leq n$. Then,
\begin{align*}
[A^TA]_{ii} = 0 & \implies \sum_{i = 1}^n [A^T]_{ik}[A]_{ki} = 0 \\
& \implies \sum_{i=1}^n [A]_{ik}^2 = 0 \\
& \implies [A]_{ik} = 0 \qquad \forall k \in \Bbb{N} \colon k \leq n.
\end{align*}
Hence, $A = \mathcal{O}_n$. $\square$

---

Now, let’s start with the proof of the result.

---

*Proof*. Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $A,B,C \in \mathcal{M}(\Bbb{K})$ such that $A = B+C$, $B^T = B$, $-C^T = C$ and $BC = \mathcal{O}_n$. Suppose that $A^2 = \mathcal{O}_n$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
A^2 = \mathcal{O}_n & \iff (B+C)(B+C)=\mathcal{O}_n \\
& \iff B^2 + BC + CB + C^2 = \mathcal{O}_n.
\end{align*}
By hypothesis, we have that
\begin{align*}
BC = \mathcal{O}_n & \iff (BC)^T = (\mathcal{O}_n)^T \\
& \iff C^TB^T = \mathcal{O}_n \\
& \iff -CB = \mathcal{O}_n \\
& \iff CB = \mathcal{O}_n.
\end{align*}
So, we have that $\mathcal{O}_n = B^2+C^2$. Then, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{O}_n = B^2 + C^2 & \iff \mathcal{O}_n = B^2(B^2 + C^2) \\
& \iff B^4 + B^2C^2 = \mathcal{O}_n \\
& \iff B^4 = \mathcal{O}_n.
\end{align*}
Then, by the previous Lemma, we have that $B^4 = \mathcal{O}_n \iff B^2 = \mathcal{O}_n \iff B = \mathcal{O}_n$. Then, it follows that $C = \mathcal{O}_n$ (because $C$ is skew symmetric and $C^2 = \mathcal{O}_n \iff CC^T = \mathcal{O}_n$). Therefore, we have that $A = \mathcal{O}_n$. $\square$

---

**My point is** be careful when using the trace of a matrix. Note that, in general, $\text{tr}A^2 = 0 \iff A = \mathcal{O}_n$ is false. The $\Longleftarrow$ implication if trivially true, but the $\implies$ implication is false (for example, take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.) Although, it is true that $\text{tr}A^2 = 0 \iff A = \mathcal{O}_n$ for symmetric matrices. (I’m gonna leave the proof of this result as an exercise).

**In short** always be careful when justifying this sort of things using the trace of a matrix.

---

Finally, I would like to suggest another solution.

---

*Proof*. Since $A = B + C$, where $B$ is a symmetric matrix and $C$ is a skew symmetric matrix, then $B = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$ and $C = \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$ (because every matrix can be expressed in a unique way as a sum of a symmetric and a skew symmetric matrices). Since $BC = \mathcal{O}$, we have that $AA^T=A^TA$. But note that $AA^T=A^TA$ is a symmetric matrix and, since $A^2 = \mathcal{O}_n$, we have that $(AA^T)^2 = \mathcal{O}_n$. Then, by our previous Lemma, we have that $AA^T = \mathcal{O}_n$. So clearly we have that $\mathcal{O}_n$. $\square$

---

This end up being too long than I expected, but if you have any doubt don’t hesitate, you can always ask. Continuation of a good work. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have nothing to pick on

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- You also have $\left(A’\right)^2=0$.
- Expend this equality in term of $B’,C’$.
- Then prove that $B=C=0$.

Comment: Your suggestion is better than nothing. I've already made it

Answer (score 0):

if you extend what you have in the original post
$\mathbf 0 = A^4 = B^4+C^4 \implies \text{trace}\big(B^4 + C^4\big)=0\implies \text{trace}\big(B^4\big) =  -1\cdot\text{trace}\big(C^4\big)$
But $C^4 =  (-C^TC)^2= (C^TC)^2$ is necessarily symmetric positive semi-definite, as is $B^4$
$\implies\text{trace}\big(B^4\big)=0=\text{trace}\big(C^4\big)\implies B^4=\mathbf 0 = C^4 \implies B=\mathbf 0=C$
since the only normal matrix that is nilpotent is the zero matrix